# WooCommerce : Create specific cart for specific product

Tags: php, wordpress, cart, wc

I'm working on the woocommerce cart. I need to create a few type of cart for specific product category. For example, a donation product category will added to Donation Cart while gifts product category will added to Gift Cart. Each cart will have difference layout.

I have do some research and got the idea to use different cart session as this plugin https://www.burningmoth.com/product/woocommerce-multiple-carts/

But I need to know how to do it. What are classes to use? What are steps to do it? The full code may not necessarily, but it is good to have one. (^_^)7